# JavaScript! Creating a Guess the word Game

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Here's code :

```
  let ccdisplay = document.querySelector('.crrDisplay');
  let incdisplay = document.querySelector('.incDisplay');
  let guess = document.querySelector('#character');
  let textForm = document.querySelector('.textForm');

           var commonWords = [
        "the", "of", "and", "a", "to", "in", "is", "you", "that", "it", 
        "he", "was", "for", "on", "are", "as", "with", "his", "they","I", "at", 
        "be","this", "have", "from", "or", "one", "had", "by", "word", "but","not",
        "what", "all", "were", "we", "when", "your", "can", "said", "there",
        "use", "an", "each", "which", "she", "do", "how", "their", "if", 
        "will","up", "other", "about", "out", "many", "then", "them",
        "these", "so","some", "her", "would", "make", "like", "him", "into", "time", "has",
         "look", "two", "more", "write", "go", "see", "number", "no", "way",
        "could", "people", "my", "than", "first", "water", "been", "call",
        "who", "oil", "its", "now", "find", "long", "down", "day", "did", 
        "get", "come", "made", "may", "part"];


  // Grabbing Random Word
  var chooseRandomWord = function(array) {
      return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }

  var chosenWord = chooseRandomWord(commonWords);
  console.log(chosenWord)

  // Function that submits the values
  textForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  var counter = 10;
  var triedCharacters = [];
  var correctCharacters = [];

  event.preventDefault();
  guess = character.value    

  for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
      chosenWord[i]
      for (z = 0; z < guess.length; z++) {
          if (guess[z] === chosenWord[i]) {
              correctCharacters.push(guess[z])
              console.log("correct " + correctCharacters)
          } 
          else {
              triedCharacters.push(guess[z])
              console.log("incorrect " + triedCharacters)
          }
      };
  }
  })
```

Hey, I'm trying to create a game that guesses the random word and put the correct ones in one array and the incorrect characters in another array the correct array works but the incorrect else isn't working and pushing in every character.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: share your entire code?

Comment: may
main.js:60 incorrect a
main.js:60 incorrect a,y
main.js:57 correct a
main.js:60 incorrect a,y,y
main.js:60 incorrect a,y,y,a
main.js:57 correct a,y

Comment: https://github.com/MateenCode/WordGame-JavaScript  this is also the github link

Comment: I would like the correct characters to go into one array and the incorrect ones in another

Comment: @MateenKazia Please provide a working code snippet

Comment: your code is completely wrong

Comment: @vegazz should they be 2 completely separate loops?

Comment: there should be only one loop and you should also check word length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only one loop. You should also loop trough shorter word but a hint with word length would be nice...

```
let display = document.querySelector('.display');
let guessQuerySelector = document.querySelector('#character');
let textForm = document.querySelector('.textForm');

var commonWords = [
  "the", "of", "and", "a", "to", "in", "is", "you", "that", "it", "he",
  "was", "for", "on", "are", "as", "with", "his", "they", "I", "at", "be",
  "this", "have", "from", "or", "one", "had", "by", "word", "but", "not",
  "what", "all", "were", "we", "when", "your", "can", "said", "there",
  "use", "an", "each", "which", "she", "do", "how", "their", "if", "will",
  "up", "other", "about", "out", "many", "then", "them", "these", "so",
  "some", "her", "would", "make", "like", "him", "into", "time", "has",
  "look", "two", "more", "write", "go", "see", "number", "no", "way",
  "could", "people", "my", "than", "first", "water", "been", "call",
  "who", "oil", "its", "now", "find", "long", "down", "day", "did", "get",
  "come", "made", "may", "part"
];

// Grabbing Random Word
var getRandomWord = function(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var randomWord = getRandomWord(commonWords);
console.log('randomWord', randomWord);

// Function that submits the values
textForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var counter = 10;
  var triedCharacters = [];
  var correctCharacters = [];

  var guessWord = guessQuerySelector.value;
  var shorterWordlength = randomWord.length > guessWord.length ? guessWord.length : randomWord.length;

  console.log('guessWord', guessWord);

  for (i = 0; i < shorterWordlength; i++) {
      if (guessWord[i] === randomWord[i]) {
        correctCharacters.push(guessWord[i])
        console.log("correct " + correctCharacters)
      } else {
        triedCharacters.push(guessWord[i])
        console.log("incorrect " + triedCharacters)
      }
  }
  randomWord = getRandomWord(commonWords);
  console.log('randomWord', randomWord);
})
```

Comment: Yes! Complete see where I went wrong, I’ll definitely fix up the front it so there some sort of hint thanks for all your help!!!